# How to shutdown a server that's configured to use XRDP for Remote Desktop [Ubuntu 10.14]?

Tags: server, shutdown, xrdp

I've configured a server to use XRDP as my remote client, instead of VNC. My problem lies in the fact that I can not remotely shutdown or restart my server from within XRDP. Choosing the shutdown or restart option just logs me out of the server, but leaves the server running. Is there a way to force it to use the correct commands, rather than logging me out?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting a command prompt on the server then running `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot and `sudo shutdown -h now` to shutdown the server?

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I am experiencing the same problem with Ubuntu Server 18.04. When running `xRDP`, choosing shutdown or restart just logs me out of the remote session (with a heavy delay, too), but does not actually execute the action. More so `MATE(-desktop)` tells me there was a problem with a system application on my next login (no matter if via `xRDP` or locally). `sudo shutdown -r now` though does indeed reboot the computer properly.